# Crucible connector for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, atlassian-crucible

I'm trying to connect Eclipse (Helios v3.6) to a Crucible server (v2.3) to be able to start and perform code reviews from the IDE, but after installing the Atlassian Connector I try to add a new Task server but I only see Bamboo and Jira.

I also noticed that in the documentation and in the plugin installation it says that Crucible and FishEye connectors are obsolete.

Has someone has figured out how to connect Eclipse to a Crucible server and enable code reviews?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After searching a bit, it looks like the last version of the Atlassian Connector to support Crucible is 2.3.

Extract from the official Atlassian website regarding Connector 3.0 release:

> Crucible reviews and some FishEye features have been removed in this version of the Connector. In the Atlassian Connector for Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA you will no longer be able to:
>
> - Create Reviews
> - View Reviews
> - Perform Reviews
> - Open files in FishEye

And it looks like there is no plan to support it again in future releases...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the support http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Working+with+Crucible+Reviews+in+Eclipse (does not work anymore) was removed but here are the eclipse update links before these are removed as well

The last version of the connector containing Crucible support is 2.3.0:
For Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6 — http://update.atlassian.com/atlassian-eclipse-plugin/2.3.0/e3.5

Comment: Location of these update sites: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/IDEPLUGIN/Installing+the+Eclipse+Connector#InstallingtheEclipseConnector-EclipseUpdateSites